# Difficulties in installing pari-jupyter kernel

Tags: installation, compiler-errors, jupyter, pari

I want to install pari-jupyter. I get the following error:

```
 PARIKernel\kernel.c(679): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pari/pari.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pari-jupyter
```

Failed to build pari-jupyter

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pari-jupyter, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How can I find pari/pari.h, and tell the compiler its location?

Comment: Have you read through [this discussion](https://github.com/sagemath/pari-jupyter/issues/23)?

Comment: Yes, but I can not understand what they mean by telling the compiler where the header is.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that fellow Windows user didn't describe how specifically they solved it.